# php: how to check if a mysql data is expired

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data in mysql format, ex: "2015-02-09 23:12:33"
Is there a way to check if this data is 24 hours or more old?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MySql Date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) functions

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(dateColumn, NOW()) as "diff" FROM tableName HAVING diff < 1;
```

*Not tested*

---

In PHP (Using PDO):

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT `dateColumn` FROM `tableName`');
$query->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

foreach ($result as $date) {
    $time = strtotime($date->dateColumn);

    if (time() - $time < 60 * 60 * 24) {
        // It's less than 24h ago;
    } else {
        // It's more than 24h ago;
    }
}
```

Just set up correct parameters for PDO to fetch rows as object.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I need to do this with php, sorry if I was not clear enough

Comment: @user3174311 Do you know that you can write MySql commands in PHP using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` functions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
 IF(yourDate<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), 1, 0) AS expired
```

or this:

```
SELECT
 IF(yourDate<DATE_SUB(NOW(), 24 HOUR), 1, 0) AS expired
```